# Libgdx How to rotate a 3D model on multiple axes with phone orientation

Tags: java, android, matrix, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to rotate a 3D model on multiple axes at once using the phone's accelerometers. When I do this, I use `setToRotation()` however, this only does one axis at a time.

For example:

```
  ModelInstance modelInstance = instances.first(); 

  //ROLL
  modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Z, phoneAccel.y*9);
  //PITCH
  modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.X, phoneAccel.z*9);
```

The phone is in forced-landscape mode. I get the instance of the model I want to rotate.

I set the `Vector3 phoneAccel` based on `Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX/Y/Z()`.

In the above example, both lines of code work correctly, but only independently. When I try to use both (one after another) the first rotate (ROLL) is removed. I would have thought the two rotation matrices would be cumulated, ie, the Z Axis is applied a rotation, and then the X Axis is applied a rotation.

Do I need to create my own cumulative rotation matrix, and then apply that at the end?

Any thoughts? Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Matrix4#setToRotation` will remove any other transformation (like rotation) previously set (hence the name "setTo"). To add a rotation transformation to an already rotated matrix, use the `rotate` method instead. This will post-multiply the transformation.

```
modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Z, phoneAccel.y*9);
modelInstance.transform.rotate(Vector3.X, phoneAccel.z*9);
```

However this will not produce your desired result, since you want the rotations to independent from each other (the rotation around the Z axis should not influence the rotation around the X axis for example). For this you can use euler angles:

```
modelInstance.transform.setFromEulerAngles(yaw, pitch, roll);
```

Comment: Thanks `setFromEulerAngles` was what I was after. Do you know if there is any overhead with this calculation behind the scenes, ie any sqrt functions?

Comment: No sqrt, but there are a couple of sin and cos calls involved (which is almost always when setting a rotation by its angle).

Comment: Actually, slight issue. This works fine for just rotation, but if I want to then move the object (translate), this doesn't work. Maybe a separate question, however, I'm using `setFromEulerAngles()` and following that a `transform.translate(x,y,z)` which is not working (no translation). If I do the translation **before** the rotation then the model rotates, but around a different origin

Comment: Use `modelInstance.transform.setFromEulerAngles(yaw, pitch, roll).trn(x, y, z);`

Answer (score 2):

The method `setToRotation` sets the model to this rotation, as the name says. This means, that you "overwrite" the rotation arround the Z-Axis and set it to a rotation ONLY arround the X-Axis.

There are different ways to do what you want to achieve:

- You can use `Quaternion`s like @noone said.
- You can use `rotate`. If you do that you need to stor your current rotation in forexample a `Vector2`, where the x value is the current rotation arround Z-Axis and the y value is the rotation arround the X-Axis.
- You can use `setToRotation`, with a custom axis, which you construct our of the `phoneAccel` values.

The `setToRotation` method gives you the posibility to define a `Vector3 direction` and a `Vector3 face`, defining which face should look to this direction.
For example:
`modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Z, Vector3.Y)` will make his top look inot Z-Direction. With a `Vector3(0, -1, 0)` his bottom (maybe his feet) will look in that direction.

Hope it is clear

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went with `setFromEulerAngles` as a solution.

Comment: @Jammo Yea in your case this is a good version to. I did not remember this. I just remember the `setToRotation` with the 2 vectors, as i needed it cause i had a given `direction` vector.