# Rotate transform to point to vector

Tags: 3d, libgdx

I am using libgdx framework. I have a character modelInstance, and an array of Vector3 objects. The character modelInstance is being translated between each Vector3 object in the array. What I am having an issue with is rotating the modelInstance to point towards the vector it is moving towards. How might once accomplish this? Below is my working code for moving the modelinstance (this method is called every render cycle while isMoving property equals true):

```
public void move(float delta){

        Vector3 start = new Vector3();
        modelInstance.transform.getTranslation(start);

        Vector3 end = pathVectors.get(0);

        float distance = start.dst(end);
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(end);
        direction.sub(start).nor();

        modelInstance.transform.trn(direction.x * moveSpeed * delta, direction.y * moveSpeed * delta, direction.z * moveSpeed * delta);

        Vector3 currentPosition = new Vector3();
        modelInstance.transform.getTranslation(currentPosition);

        if(start.dst(currentPosition) >= distance){

            modelInstance.transform.setTranslation(end);

            pathVectors.remove(0);
            if(pathVectors.isEmpty()){
                isMoving = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to change the orientation of your model, then I suggest you check out [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837736/libgdx-how-to-rotate-a-3d-model-on-multiple-axes-with-phone-orientation). Ignoring the stuff he's doing with the phone, it shows how to change the rotation.

If you're trying to make the rotation more gradual, you might want to take a look at [`Vector3#lerp()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html#lerp-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-float-), [`Vector3#slerp()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html#slerp-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-float-), or [`Vector3#interpolate()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.html#interpolate-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-float-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Interpolation-), all of which would allow you to incrementally rotate the model between its current orientation and the `direction` that you have defined in your code.